# Pattern Generator

Tags: c++, loops, nested

I'm a newbie in C++ and I'm supposed to write a program for a pattern generator that prints 2 different characters with different frequencies (input by user). The number of rows and columns are also determined by user.

For example, ‘*’ must be repeated three times and ‘+’ twice in 4 rows of 21
column, the pattern should look like this:

```
***++***++***++***++*
**++***++***++***++**
*++***++***++***++***
++***++***++***++***+
```

However my output is giving me 21 columns and 20 rows which I think makes the 'rows' variable in my code below useless, but I'm not sure why this is happening.

My output:

```
***++***++***++***++*
**++***++***++***++**
*++***++***++***++***
++***++***++***++***+
+***++***++***++***++
***++***++***++***++*
**++***++***++***++**
*++***++***++***++***
++***++***++***++***+
+***++***++***++***++
***++***++***++***++*
**++***++***++***++**
*++***++***++***++***
++***++***++***++***+
+***++***++***++***++
***++***++***++***++*
**++***++***++***++**
*++***++***++***++***
++***++***++***++***+
+***++***++***++***++
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a, b;
    int n,                  // number of times char a is repeated
        m,                  // number of times char b is repeated
        rows,               // number of rows
        columns,            // number of columns
        sumCharInRow = 0;
        
    cout << "Please input your first character: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "How many times should this character be repeated?: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    cout << "Please input your second character: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "How many times should this character be repeated?: ";
    cin >> m;
    
    cout << "Please input the number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Please input the number of columns: ";
    cin >> columns;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                cout << a;      
                sumCharInRow++; 
                
                if (sumCharInRow >= columns) {
                    cout << "\n";
                    sumCharInRow = 0;
                }
            }
            
            for (int l = 0; l < m; l++) {
                cout << b;
                sumCharInRow++;
                
                if (sumCharInRow >= columns) {
                    cout << "\n";
                    sumCharInRow = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can I know why it's not giving the expected output because I'm stumped. And also I'd really love to see what are the better alternatives to write this program. Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: I understand that "using namespace std" is borderline a crime in C++ but for the sake of readability of this simple program, my lecturer insists that we use this.

Comment: Two most-nested loops together print `n + m` characters. This is repeated `columns * rows` times by the two outer loops, for a total of `(n+m)*colums*rows` characters printed (not counting line breaks). Whereas you are supposed to print only `colums*rows` characters in total. That's how you end up with 5 times more rows than you expected - `5 == 2 + 3`

Comment: Next time, use the debugger in your IDE to step by step through loops like these, it will help so much in figuring out just what's going on.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for your explanation. Can I get an idea on how I can fix this? Is it anything to do with the increment of `j++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over each case of the matrix, but print several char for each.

You might select which character to print to keep your 2 loops:

```
void print_pattern(int col, int row, char c1, char c2, int n1, int n2)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j != row; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i != col; ++i) {
            std::cout << (counter < n1 ? c1 : c2);
            if (++counter == n1 + n2) {
                counter = 0;   
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aadad558229c3aac)

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your response. However can I ask how does `counter < n1 ? c1 : c2` work?

Comment: `cond ? value1: value2` is [ternary operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator), similar to `if`/`else`.

Comment: `counter` is the variable to keep track on where we are in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Remove columns for loop and add continue statement whenever sum surpasses column. Update the later portion of your code as follows

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows;) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            cout << a;      
            sumCharInRow++; 
            
            if (sumCharInRow >= columns) {
                cout << "\n";
                i++;
                sumCharInRow = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

         if (sumCharInRow >= columns)
             continue;
        
        for (int l = 0; l < m; l++) {
            cout << b;
            sumCharInRow++;
            
            if (sumCharInRow >= columns) {
                cout << "\n";
                i++;
                sumCharInRow = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Ive tested your code but the output I got is `***++***++***++***++`

Comment: What is the value of columns variable??

Comment: 21, I used the same as the sample (4 rows, 21 columns)

Comment: I am sorry, I have edited the post and declaring the sumCharInRow variable inside for loop was a big mistake. I am so sorry

Comment: `continue;` as last statement of loop is useless (you continue inner loop, not outer one) and if you leave the inner loop (with `break`), you loose count for the pattern.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes you are right. I totally forgot that it's inside another for loop. Your answer is way better. For some reason, I cannot delete my answer idk why